# Android - several layout changes when changing orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I have an ImageView which I scale using a matrix. I've set

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

so I will handle the orientation manually. I've this code which calculate the image view after an orientation change:

```
           final ViewTreeObserver observer= mCanvasImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
       observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {


                int w = mCanvasImageView.getWidth();
                int h = mCanvasImageView.getHeight();

                System.out.println("w=" + w + ",h=" + h);
```

for some reason, instead of having just two states for the ImageView (one in portrait and one in landscape), there is a third pair of width and height values.

Anyone knows why there seems to be this third, temporary calculation? and how do I distinguish it from the real values?